# Button click event

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a button in my program that supposed to be clicked after a while loop finished, whats the code to click the button?

Comment: Why make it a button if the user isn't going to do anything with it?

Comment: A winforms button or some other sort of button?

Comment: I know it doesn't look intellectual at all, but its a server that will begin to listen by clicking the button, and should doing it continually, but can't put it in a loop. because will crash, so that was the best idea i could come with, close connection after each time receiving and start again.

Comment: @ jeffamaphone : a winform button

Comment: How does adding a button solve the crash problem? I assume its a UI hang because long running process on the UI thread, but a programmatic button click will not help.  The Backgroundworker suggestion below makes sense, but if this is a straight and continuous polling thread then a timer makes more sense than a button click. Then you don't have to worry about potential issues with multiple button clicks or timing of button clicks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To programatically click a button just call the `Click` method:

```
button.Click();
```

Note that this doesn't cause the UI to update as if the button had been pressed - it just results in the event handler for the click event being run.

In your question you mention that you are running a while loop that presumably takes some time. If you do this in the naive way - running it in the main application thread - it will cause the UI to block while the loop is running. To fix this you need to run the while loop in another thread, for example by using a [`BackgroundWorker`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx). But then when your loop finishes you have to be careful to ensure that the click event is called back on the main thread. The general way to do this is to use Invoke, but in the specific case that you have a BackgroundWorker you can run the code after the loop finishes in the [`OnRunWorkerCompleted`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.onrunworkercompleted.aspx) event handler then you don't need to call Invoke yourself as the BackgroundWorker takes care of this for you.